# How do I create a *public* Facebook community page using the Open Graph protocol?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to integrate pages from a site I am building into the Facebook Open Graph. My goal is to create a Facebook "Community Page" for each cause in my application. I have added Open Graph tags to a page so that I can Like it in Facebook, and a community page corresponding to my cause has been added to Facebook. However, I am the only one who can see the community page, since I am its administrator. All other users are redirected to the URL of the cause itself.

My community page is at:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Kings-Hospital-Garden-Short-Term-Aid/123353527700762

When fans go to this page, I would like them to see the Facebook community page rather than being redirected. In other words, I want my community page to behave like the following community page referenced in all of the [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) on the subject:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Rock/109550739071923

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I asked this same question on the [Facebook Platform Developer Forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=60881), but I suspect that the SO community may be more quick to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it seems like community pages are generated from existing connections in user profiles, and not by the like button implemented on external sites.  In your example, "liking" "The Rock" on IMDB does not add "The Rock" community page as one of your interests.  It *does* do the following things:

- Indicates you "liked The Rock on IMDB" in your profile (recent activity)
- Adds "The Rock" *link* to your "movie" interests/likes in your profile (since it's OG type is movie)
- Posts you "liked the Rock on IMDB" to friends streams (depends on OG data specified)
- Adds the *link* to the page to search results (which is what is happening in your case)

I know FB may have implied "likes" would generate community pages during their keynote, so like a lot of their other functionality it may change in the future